# Change the same css class property through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, target

I have a same class in multiple pages. And I have a control on css though which I can change the property of the css.

```
div.single-column div.middle {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}
```

In one page I want to make `top:70px` and rest of the pages I want it `top:0`

Is there any way I can control this through JavaScript on one page?

Comment: Please share your working code.

Comment: Why do you want to use javascript to do this, you can just use two separate CSS classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your css make a default `top : 0px;`

```
div.single-column div.middle {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

and in your page you want `top : 70px` just add in this page

```
<style>
div.single-column div.middle {
    top: 70px !important;
}
<style>
```

Comment: whilte it works, it's far from being the best way of solving this problem - embedding CSS in your markup makes maintenance more complicated, when you can easily have cascading selectors. @PraveenKumar's answer offers a much better approach

Answer (score 1):

Say you are using two pages:

- `main.html`
- `sub1.html`
- `sub2.html`

In `main.html`, for the `<body>` give a class like:

```
<body class="main">
```

And for both the sub pages, use:

```
<body class="sub">
```

And give the CSS like this:

```css
.main .middle {top: 0px;}
.sub .middle {top: 70px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
if(window.location.href == "URL"){
document.getElementsByTagName("Body").style.top = "100px";
}else{
document.getElementsByTagName("Body").style.top = "200px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can edit the html:

```
div.single-column div.middle {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; // default
}

div.single-column div.middle--alt {
    top: 70px;
} // modifier, a la BEM
```

in your markup on the all pages:

```
<div class="middle">...</div>
```

and on the page(s) that need `top: 70px`:

```
<div class="middle middle--alt">
```

if you could simplify your selectors to `.middle` and `.middle--alt` that's great, but it might not be the case as we don't know the rest of your css.

It's one of the possible 'proper' CSS way of solving your problem. However, if you can't edit the markup, see if you can use any cascading hooks (like in Praveen's answer) - otherwise you might have to use JS assuming that you can at least control what is loaded/executed on each page. Keep in mind that this kind of changes might incur in some FOUC (Flashing of unstyled content) due to the fact that your js will be likely applied after the dom is rendered and the css applied.